# Automatizar actualizacion de vista en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, data, datos

Hola tengo una duda sobre automatizacion de procesos en SQL, desconozco si lo que voy a preguntar es posible de realizar pero les presento:

Tengo una tabla con una estructura como esta llamada T1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cree una vista con este codigo:`

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
SELECT
    [columna1],
    [columna2],
    [columna3],
    COUNT ([columna4]) AS columna4,
    COUNT ([columna5]) AS columna5
FROM T1
GROUP BY [columna1], [columna2], [columna3]

`
```

Ahora lo que quiero lograr, es que toda vez que sea añadida una nueva columna en la tabla T1 la vista V1 modifique su codigo.

Por ejemplo fue añadida la columna 6  en T1:

```
    ALTER TABLE T1
    ADD [Columna6] INT

INSERT INTO T1 ([Columna6])
VALUES (6),
       (12);
```

Por lo tanto ahora T1 se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria lograr que automaticamente el codigo de la vista V1 se actualice a este:

```
ALTER VIEW V1 AS
    SELECT
        [columna1],
        [columna2],
        [columna3],
        COUNT ([columna4]) AS columna4,
        COUNT ([columna5]) AS columna5,
        COUNT ([columna6]) AS columna6
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY [columna1], [columna2], [columna3]
```

Y asi suscesivamente cada vez que se añadan nuevas columnas a T1.

Es esto posible? como puedo lograrlo?

Nota: Intente con un trigger pero fue un poco rebuscado y no funciono, nose si con un cursor se puede hacer o si hay otra alternativa que este omitiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como poder, si que se puede hacer desde, por ejemplo un procedimiento almacenado. Ya que ahí tienes la capacidad de modificar la estructura de la base de datos.

**Dudo mucho que sea aconsejable**, pero si es viable, y te surgirán de vez en cuando problemas. Por ejemplo si la definición de la vista pasa de 4000 caracteres.

Yo te voy a dar una solución a lo que indicas, pero hay que tener en cuenta, que la definición de la vista es muy simple y que puede haber muchas cosas que se escapen.

Al escenario que indicas, le he añadido dos columnas.

```
drop table if exists t1;
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   [columna1] int,
   [columna2] int,
   [columna3] int,
   [columna4] int,
   [columna5] int
)
go
INSERT INTO t1 (columna1, columna2, columna3, columna4, columna5)
values 
(1,2,3,4,5),
(6,7,8,9,10);
go
drop view if exists dbo.v1;
go
CREATE VIEW dbo.V1 AS
SELECT
    [columna1],
    [columna2],
    [columna3],
    COUNT ([columna4]) AS columna4,
    COUNT ([columna5]) AS columna5
FROM T1
GROUP BY [columna1], [columna2], [columna3]
GO

Alter table t1
add [columna6] int;
Alter table t1
add [columna7] int;
```

Ahora con un procedure.

```
Create or alter procedure
addColumnsT1
As
Begin
    -- variable de tabla para tener las columnas que tiene la tabla y no la vista.
    Declare @tableNames table (NewColumnName nvarchar(128));
    Insert into @tableNames (NewColumnName)
    Select t.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  t
    where t.TABLE_NAME = 'T1'
    AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    except 
    Select t.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T
    where t.TABLE_NAME = 'V1'
    AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' ;

    -- IDENTIFICAMOS LAS COLUMNAS NUEVAS
    DECLARE @CountColumn NVARCHAR(MAX);

     -- Preparamos las columnas con su alias
     SELECT @CountColumn= STUFF(
     (
     SELECT
       ',COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(NewColumnName)) + ') AS '+ QUOTENAME(LTRIM(NewColumnName))
     FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT NewColumnName 
        FROM @tableNames T
       ) AS T
     ORDER BY
     NewColumnName
     FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '');
     
    IF @CountColumn IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Obtenemos la definición de la vista.
        Declare @objectDefinition nvarchar(max);
        SELECT @objectDefinition= OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('dbo.v1'));
        
        -- COGEMOS LA PARTE ANTERIOR AL FROM
        DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @FROM INT = (PATINDEX('%FROM T1%',@objectDefinition)) -1;
        
        SELECT @QUERY=LEFT(@objectDefinition, @FROM);

        -- LE ANEXAMOS LAS COLUMNAS DEL COUNT
        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, N', ',@CountColumn, ' ');

        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, SUBSTRING(@objectDefinition, @FROM, LEN(@objectDefinition)));

        SET @QUERY = REPLACE(@QUERY,'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW');

        -- CAMBIAMOS LAS NUEVAS COLUMNAS
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY;

        --REFRESCAMOS LA DEFINICIÓN DE LOS METADATOS DE LA VISTA.
        DECLARE @VIEWNAME NVARCHAR(128) = N'V1';
        EXECUTE sp_refreshview @ViewName;
    END
END
GO
```

Y su ejecución...

Si leemos la vista ahora.

[image: Res1]

Pero si ejecutamos el procedure y luego leemos la vista.

[image: Res2]